# Random access to an enumeration of sorted sets of 3 symbols from a fixed alphabet

Tags: algorithm, sorting, combinatorics

Imagine we have an alphabet of, say, 5 chars: **ABCDE**.

We now want to enumerate all possible sets of 3 of those letters. Each letter can only be present once is a set, and the order of letters doesn't matter (hence the letters in the set should be sorted).

So we get the following sets:

1. ABC
2. ABD
3. ABE
4. ACD
5. ACE
6. ADE
7. BCD
8. BCE
9. BDE
10. CDE

For a total of 10 sets. The order is lexicographical.

Let's now assume that the alphabet length is `N` (5 in this example) and the length of the set in `M` (3 in this example). Knowing `N` and `M`, how could we, if at all possible:

1. Tell the total number of combinations in at worst `O(M+N)` (the answer is 10 in this example)?
2. Output the combination with any given number (given 1, return ABC; given 5, return ACE and so on) in at worst `O(M+N)`?

It's trivial to do those things with `O(M^N)` complexity by generating the whole list, but I wonder if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is straightforward: it is `C(n,r)`, where we are to choose all combinations of `r` items from a set of size `n`. The formula is [here](http://www.mathwords.com/c/combination_formula.htm) among other places:

```
C(n,r) = n! / (r! (n-r)!)
```

The ability to select the `i'th` combination without computing all the others will depend on having an encoding that relates the combination number `i` to the combination. That would be much more challenging and will require more thought ...

(EDIT)

Having given the problem more thought, a solution looks like this in Python:

```
from math import factorial

def combination(n,r):
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * factorial(n-r))

alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

def showComb(n,r,i,a):
    if r < 1:
        return ""
    rr = r-1
    nn = max(n-1,rr)
    lasti = i
    i -= combination(nn,rr)
    j = 0
    while i > 0:
        j += 1
        nn = max(nn-1,1)
        rr = min(rr,nn)    # corrected this line in second edit
        lasti = i
        i -= combination(nn,rr)
    return a[j] + showComb(n-j-1,r-1,lasti,a[(j+1):])

for i in range(10):
    print(showComb(5,3,i+1,alphabet))
```

... which outputs the list shown in the question.

The approach I've used is to find the first element of the `i'th` output set using the idea that the number of combinations of the remaining set elements can be used to find which should be the first element for a given number `i`.

That is, for C(5,3), the first C(4,2) (=6) output sets have 'A' as their first character, then the next C(3,1) (=3) output sets have 'B' then C(1,1) (=1) sets have 'C' as their first character.

The function then finds the remaining elements recursively. Note that `showComb()` is tail-recursive so it could be expressed as a loop if you preferred, but I think the recursive version is easier to understand in this case.

For further testing, the following code may be useful:

```
import itertools

def showCombIter(n,r,i,a):
    return ''.join(list(itertools.combinations(a[0:n],r))[i-1])

print ("\n")

# Testing for other cases   
for i in range(120):
    x = showComb(10,3,i+1,alphabet)
    y = showCombIter(10,3,i+1,alphabet)
    print(i+1,"\t",x==y,"\t",x,y)
```

... which confirms that all 120 examples of this case are correct.

I haven't calculated the time complexity exactly but the number of calls to `showComb()` will be `r` and the `while` loop will execute `n` times or fewer. Thus, in the terminology of the question, I am pretty sure the complexity will be less than O(M+N), if we assume that the `factorial()` function can be calculated in constant time, which I don't think is a bad approximation unless its implementation is naive.

Comment: Looks great! I've been tinkering with your solution and tried to change the loop to `for i in range(120): print(showComb(10,3,i+1,alphabet))`. It produces wrong combinations and crashes though.

Comment: @dragonroot: Thanks for the testing! Yes, there was a bug in the code that showed up when `n-r` was larger than 2. I've corrected it in the edited answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Agree the first part is easy, put a similar equation to this into a language of your choice.

```
x=12
y=5
z=1
base=1
until [[ $z -gt y ]]
do
 base=`echo $x $z $base|awk '{print ($1/$2) * $3}'`
 x=`expr $x - 1`
 z=`expr $z + 1`
 echo base:$base
done

echo $base
```

The above example uses 12 Items, arranged in sets of 5 for 792 combinations.

To do the second part of your question... I am just thinking about it, but it is not straight forward by any stretch.